# Amazon SES - Domain Verification - Does it expire?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dkim, amazon-ses

I read [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html) about verifying domains in [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/), and I don't understand - how long does the domain verification last and does it expire?

What happens if I remove the DNS settings after I verified a domain? I tried to do it with the [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) DNS settings, and there I received a notification that the DKIM of the domain would be revoked, unless I restored them. But with the domain itself, I removed the DNS settings and I didn't receive any notification.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this information, you should leave the [TXT record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TXT_record) in place: *[Creating and verifying identities in Amazon SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verified-domain-revocation.html)*:

> "Amazon SES periodically reviews domain verification status, and revokes verification in cases where it is no longer valid. If Amazon SES is unable to detect the TXT record information required to confirm ownership of a domain, you will receive an Amazon SES Domain Verification REVOCATION WARNING email from Amazon SES."

Else, after the next check by AWS, they will revoke the verification. They will warn you about the pending revocation though and give you 72 hours to react.

--Edit--

Unfortunately the original Answer has been removed from the linked AWS resource. Another site referencing the same original resource can be found here: *[Removing Domain Verification Record after verification in SES](https://repost.aws/questions/QU_1KpLIEmSQ29JEZr5YpSEQ/removing-domain-verification-record-after-verification-in-ses)*

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice this page. The specific domain I'm using is just for testing, I don't mind if it will be revoked.

Comment: I noticed that the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verified-domain-revocation.html has been removed and replaced by AWS. Is this still relevant?

Comment: @Uri Not sure I understand. What do you mean with "the link has been removed and replaced by AWS"? I can still access the link above...
Peter Mortensen edited my post to make it look prettier. Is that what you refer to?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verified-domain-revocation.html redirects to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/creating-identities.html, and I can't find information about domain revocation on this page.

Comment: @Uri It looks like AWS removed that original post with the containing info. Sadly I could not find the info anywhere else, except for another Q&A portal referencing the same resource that I used: https://repost.aws/questions/QU_1KpLIEmSQ29JEZr5YpSEQ/removing-domain-verification-record-after-verification-in-ses
I have edited my answer above accordingly.